# Regex Python remove between styling tags (\n\r included)

Tags: python, css, regex

I'm kinda confused with regexp i got this text, which needs to remove styling inside the tags. I got it working if it is on a one line like this with this regexp `<style>(.*)<\/style>`, pretty easy:

```
<style>@page { size: 8.5in 11in; margin-right: 1in; margin-top: 0.5in; margin-bottom: 0.5in }</style>
```

However I stuck with `\r\n` which I can't defeat for this text.

```
<style>
    @page { size: 8.5in 11in; margin-right: 1in; margin-top: 0.5in; margin-bottom: 0.5in }
    p { margin-bottom: 0.17in; direction: ltr; color: #000000; widows: 2; orphans: 2 }
    p.western { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 12pt; so-language: en-US; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold }
    p.cjk { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 12pt; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold }
    p.ctl { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 10pt; so-language: ar-SA }
    h3 { margin-top: 0in; margin-bottom: 0.17in; direction: ltr; color: #000000; text-align: justify; widows: 2; orphans: 2; page-break-after: auto }
    h3.western { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 12pt; so-language: en-US; font-weight: normal }
    h3.cjk { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: normal }
    h3.ctl { font-family: "Times New Roman", serif; font-size: 10pt; so-language: ar-SA; font-weight: normal }
    a:link { color: #0000ff }
    a:visited { color: #800080 }
    a.western:visited { so-language: en-US }
    a.cjk:visited { so-language: zh-CN }
    a.ctl:visited { so-language: hi-IN }
    a.sdfootnotesym-western { font-size: 8pt }
    a.sdfootnotesym-cjk { font-size: 8pt }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the s modifier.

> (?s) for "single line mode" makes the dot match all characters,
>   including line breaks. Not supported by Ruby or JavaScript. In Tcl,
>   (?s) also makes the caret and dollar match at the start and end of the
>   string only.

Or use:

```
<style>([\s\S]*)<\/style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `(?s)`(*DOTALL*) modifier to make dot to match newline character also,

```
(?s)<style>(.*?)<\/style>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dI1xA7/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex, '.' does not include \n

```
<style>((?:.|\n)*)<\/style>
```